# Flutter: use Expanded inside a SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, singlechildscrollview

I have a page for filling out forms
There is a flexible Expanded between each input box for interval. Their flex is different.
I hope that when the keyboard pops up, these Expanded will be compressed first, and if the height is still not enough, then the column will be scrollable.
eg:

[When there is no keyboard, Expanded will occupy as high as possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt0MJ.png)

[When the keyboard is raised, it will compress Expanded as much as possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CeDz.png)

[But when there are enough TextFields, I cannot make the Column scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVpP0.png)

```
Scaffold(
    // body: SingleChildScrollView(
    //   child: Container(
    //     constraints: BoxConstraints(
    //       maxHeight: 812.h,
    //       minHeight: 300.h
    //     ),
    //     child: Column(
    //       children: [
    //         Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.red)),
    //         TextFormField(),
    //         Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.yellow,)),
    //         TextFormField(),
    //         Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.green,)),
    //         TextFormField(),
    //         Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.blue,)),
    //         TextFormField(),
    //         Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.purple,))
    //       ],
    //     ),
    //   ),
    // ),
    body: Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
          maxHeight: 812.h,
          minHeight: 300.h
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.red)),
          TextFormField(),
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.yellow,)),
          TextFormField(),
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.green,)),
          TextFormField(),
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.blue,)),
          TextFormField(),
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.purple,)),
          TextFormField(),
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.purple,)),
          TextFormField(),
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.purple,)),
          TextFormField(),
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.purple,)),
          TextFormField(),
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.purple,)),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to add your column inside SingleChildScrollView() try below code and I think no need to use **Expanded** for column direct use **TextFormField**

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.red)),
      TextFormField(),
      Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.yellow,)),
      TextFormField(),
      Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.green,)),
      TextFormField(),
      Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.blue,)),
      TextFormField(),
      Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.purple,)),
      TextFormField(),
      Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.purple,)),
      TextFormField(),
      Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.purple,)),
      TextFormField(),
      Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.purple,)),
      TextFormField(),
      Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.purple,)),
    ],
  ),
),
)
```

Comment: This is just an example. Actually, in my real needs, I need to use Expanded for layout with different flex coefficients.